# Timeline for availablity of azure search indexing on ADLS Gen2

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Our team is heavily using ADLS gen2 to store our analytical data. We want to build azure search indexes on top of this data. But seems like currently azure search doesn't support indexing on ADLS Gen2. Is there any guidance on the timeline when it would be supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct that we do not currently support ADLS Gen2 as a source for our Azure Search indexer.  This is in the works, however we do not have a timeline I can provide yet.

In the meantime, you can use our PUSH api to programmatically send content from it to Azure Search.

Answer (score 0):

We have announced a public preview of an indexer that supports Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 as a data source.

Request access to the preview here:
https://aka.ms/azure-cognitive-search/indexer-preview

More documentation on the preview indexer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-howto-index-azure-data-lake-storage